# Detecting whether image is displayed in iframe or in isolation

Tags: php, javascript, browser, iframe, thickbox

I am building a system that allows people to view pictures through [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/).  But I have a problem.  The picture in the thickbox gets displayed directly through PHP and normal HTML. It gets displayed without any CSS interface and the page just views the plain picture. This is fine if the picture is viewed through the thickbox.  But if the user wanted to open more than 1 picture at the same time, the user might open the pics on new tabs, and in this case the picture will be displayed on the the page without anything.  And that won't look good.

How can I detect if the user is viewing the picture through the thickbox or through the whole browser as a full page?

Comment: the code is the normal html and thickbox implementation code... but is there anyway to check if it is opened through the thickbox or the full browser

Comment: @Awah. Please post it, otherwise, we cannot see what's wrong with the code and thus help you.

Comment: @onesimusUnbound. there is nothing on the code.. the code is working fine.. but what i am asking is how can i check if the picture is being viewed using the thickbox or not!<BR> but if the code is that importnat then here it is:<BR><BR>

Comment: <a href="view_picture.php?pid=<?php echo $pid; ?>" class="thickbox" rel="gallery-plants"><img src="<?php echo $cover; ?>" /></a>

Comment: the pid is a variable that has the picture id.. the view_picture.php will run the pid in a database and get the path of the picture...

the picture will be viewed as if the picture is being viewed directly.. i mean the way the view_picture.php will open the picture as if it is opened directly like pic.jpg.. does this make sense now??

Comment: I've added [php] tag in case some can help you since I do not know how to code in PHP. BTW, [Thickbox isn't supported](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/).

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this would be to modify your `view_picture.php` file to include an argument that states what format the view is currently in. For example:

```
<a href="view_picture.php?pid=<?php echo $pid; ?>&view=thickbox" class="thickbox" rel="gallery-plants"><img src="<?php echo $cover; ?>" /></a>
```

*Note the addition of `&view=thickbox` to the `href` attribute*

Then in your `view_picture.php` something like the following:

```
if($_GET['view'] !== 'thickbox'){
    // display the picture with other html etc
}
else {
    // display the picture without any extra content (as it is currently)
}
```